smooth transition effect with tailwind and nextjs
I have some mistake here in below code.
I want to do this smooth transition effect
like this in product images
check it here: https://demo.ar-themes.com/hanout/product/%d8%af%d9%85%d9%8a%d8%a9/

I try to do it like this but not close
this is my page product
"use client";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Header from "@/app/_components/Header/Header";
import Footer from "../../_components/Footer/index";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useTheme } from "@/app/_context/ThemeContext";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import { ChevronLeft, ChevronRight } from "lucide-react";

function Page() {
  const [select, setSelect] = useState(0);
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const { products, mainColor } = useTheme();
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const url = decodeURIComponent(pathname.split("/").pop());
  const product = products.find((product) => product?.attributes?.url === url);

  const figureRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (figureRef.current) {
      figureRef.current.style.transition =
        "transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.795, -0.035, 0, 1)";
      figureRef.current.style.transform = `translate3d(-${
        select * 100
      }%, 0, 0)`;
    }
  }, [select]);

  if (!product) {
    return <div>Product not found</div>;
  }

  const nextThumbnails = () => {
    if (select + 1 < product?.attributes?.files?.data?.length) {
      setSelect(select + 1);
    }
  };

  const prevThumbnails = () => {
    if (select > 0) {
      setSelect(select - 1);
    }
  };

  const openModal = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(true);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />

      <section className="w-full mx-auto px-4 md:px-6 py-8">
        <div className="grid lg:grid-cols-2 gap-6 items-start">
          <div className="w-[70%] relative overflow-hidden">
            <div className="figure" ref={figureRef}>
              {product?.attributes?.files?.data.map((image, index) => (
                <Image
                  key={index}
                  src={image?.attributes?.url}
                  width={image?.attributes?.width}
                  height={image?.attributes?.height}
                  className={`rounded-lg w-full object-cover h-auto `}
                  onClick={openModal}
                />
              ))}
            </div>
            <div className="grid grid-cols-6 gap-2 mt-3 w-full">
              <div className="w-full h-full flex justify-between items-center">
                <ChevronRight
                  onClick={prevThumbnails}
                  className={`${
                    select === 0 ? "cursor-not-allowed" : "cursor-pointer"
                  }`}
                  size={50}
                  color={mainColor}
                />
              </div>
              {product?.attributes?.files?.data.map((image, index) => (
                <div key={index} className="cursor-pointer">
                  <Image
                    src={image?.attributes?.url}
                    onClick={() => setSelect(index)}
                    width={image?.attributes?.width}
                    height={image?.attributes?.height}
                    className={`rounded-lg object-cover  w-full aspect-square cursor-pointer border-2 ${
                      select === index && "border-main"
                    }`}
                  />
                </div>
              ))}
              <div className="w-full h-full flex justify-between items-center">
                <ChevronLeft
                  onClick={nextThumbnails}
                  className={`${
                    select + 1 === product?.attributes?.files?.data?.length
                      ? "cursor-not-allowed"
                      : "cursor-pointer"
                  }`}
                  size={50}
                  color={mainColor}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="w-[30%]"></div>
        </div>
      </section>

      {isModalOpen && (
        <div
          className={`fixed inset-0 z-[8000000000] flex items-center justify-center bg-black bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity duration-300 ${
            isModalOpen ? "opacity-100" : "opacity-0"
          }`}
          onClick={closeModal}
        >
          <div className="relative transition-transform transform scale-100">
            <Image
              src={product?.attributes?.files?.data[select]?.attributes.url}
              width={600}
              height={600}
              className="rounded-lg object-cover w-full h-auto transition-opacity duration-300 ease-in-out"
            />
            <button
              className="absolute top-4 right-4 text-white text-2xl"
              onClick={closeModal}
            >
              &times;
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}

      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Page;

this is global css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

:root {
  --foreground-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  --background-start-rgb: 214, 219, 220;
  --background-end-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
  --main-color: #000; /* Default value */
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --foreground-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --background-start-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
    --background-end-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  }
}

.figure {
  display: flex; /* Align images horizontally */
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.795, -0.035, 0, 1); /* Smooth 3D effect */
  transform-style: preserve-3d; /* Preserve 3D transform for child elements */
  will-change: transform; /* Optimize the transition performance */
}

.figure img {
  backface-visibility: hidden; /* Prevent the images from being visible during the flip */
  width: 100%; /* Ensure images take full width */
  height: auto; /* Maintain aspect ratio */
}
body {
  color: rgb(var(--foreground-rgb));
}

@layer utilities {
  .text-balance {
    text-wrap: balance;
  }
}

I try only CSS but it didn't work
so I try this in the code;
it works but just for the first image
so please help me

That's a lot of code. Please try to make a Minimal, Reproducible Example on CodeSandbox / CodePen
